# Suggestion to Improve Or Release Memory Space Without Change the Code

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, memory-leaks, asp.net-3.5

We have a site with huge usage of Memory, this site is in .NET FrameWork 3.5 and hosted in IIS 7.5 With App Pool .NET2 in Classic mode on Windows Server 2008 R2. In this case the server memory (RAM) is 64G and in 4-5 hours all the memory allocated. and the most used memory process is w3wp. For some reasons we can't change the code or change classic mode to integrated.

And the question is what options we have to improve memory usage without change the code? any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure it's IIS 7.5? I didn't think you could get that on Windows Server 2003? Maybe you meant Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: @Damon My Mistake the server is 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recycling the application pool will give you a fresh start. You can configure the application pool that your application is configured to run on, to recycle every two-three hours.

[Read about Application Pool Recycling here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754494%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this is an Option

Comment: Depending on whether (and how) your maintain sessions, this may effectively log out all currently connected clients, but I don't think there's an option to avoid this. Up-voted.